# cannot read php://input when request content type is multipart/form-data

Tags: php

From http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php:
php://input is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

My questions are :

1. *why* it's not available?
2. are there any more cases when I cannot get raw request data other than when content type is `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Did you get a var_dump($_POST/$_GET); What does it say?

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. Its about how PHP works, not about how my script works

Comment: WOW, I had no idea PHP was multi-threaded at that level, interesting.

Comment: So you think it behaves this way because this content type is parsed via multiple threads?

Comment: An input thread, and an output thread. I never thought about PHP at that level, just that I would let it do its thing, and build upon it.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get what you mean by input thread and output thread. I/O streams I do understand

Comment: I completely didn't understand your question, and now I get that there's 2+ thread control in PHP.

Comment: Dude, i guess youre mixing threads and streams

Comment: I'd advise you to rtfm before trying to answer serious questions :p

Comment: a thread and a stream are the same thing for the most part.

Comment: Lol. No. Those are completely different things. Stream is about data, thread is about process. Totally different ;)